# Can we have a "no longer reproducible" close reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Stack Overflow has this as one of their custom close reasons:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

I think that something like this would be helpful for our site. Do we want this close reason for Arduino SE? Should it be rewritten? What do you guys think?

One question that I would like to close with this proposed close reason is this question: [Arduino UNO code ignores variables selectively](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/11738/arduino-uno-code-ignores-variables-selectively/11788#11788) (It'd also be helpful for using the wrong baud rate)

Comment: This one, too: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13671/doesnt-work-radio-transmission-from-arduino-uno-to-arduino-pro-micro/13725#13725

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/16296/using-an-arduino-as-a-electrical-mains-switch

Comment: This one, too: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17476/why-is-my-tmp35-giving-me-weird-values/17589#17589